# How to calculate multiple columns of data?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1465 observations and 1074 variables. I am using the TTR package in order to calculate EMA. The problem is I need to calculate it for each of the 1074 columns. Each Column is a stock ticker.

I can easily calculate it for a single column like this:

```
LMA[,63] <- EMA(LMA[,63], 45)
```

I have tried to calculate it as follows:

```
LMA[1:ncol(df)] <- EMA(LMA[1:ncol(df)], 45)
```

but it seems that the data is not passed to the EMA function as separate columns of data.

How do I make it calculate it for all the columns (stocks) separately?

Comment: You can try `LMA[] <- lapply(LMA, function(x) EMA(x, 45))` (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` in the following way, assuming the dataframe is of stock tickers is `df`, and that it only has numeric variables.

```
library(TTR)
LMA <- apply(df, 2, FUN = EMA, n = 45)
```

And this returns an array of the same size as `df` with `EMA` applied.

Comment: Thank you so much, @vpipkt! I did try the `apply` function but my understanding of R is still very limited. I tried to insert the `EMA` function incorrectly for use in the `apply` function.

Comment: @akrun, I just changed the "1" to "2" which then calculates it as columns! :D

Comment: Okay I have changed the margin to 2. My mistake. Still working on my second cup of coffee ;-)

Comment: Good to see that you changed it.  Anyway, +1 for your approach though I prefer `lapply` for data.frames

Comment: @akrun and the possibility of using the wrong margin argument is a good reason to use `lapply`. It makes good use of the underlying structure that data.frame is a list of vectors.

Comment: I understand that `apply` is more flexible fto use because of the MARGIN argument and I use it with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `data.frame`, we can use `lapply` to loop through the columns

```
library(TTR)
LMA[] <- lapply(LMA, EMA, n=45)
```

Using an example from `?EMA`, I am changing the 2nd to 5th columns in `data(ttrc)` with the `EMA` values

```
data(ttrc)
ttrc[2:5] <- lapply(ttrc[2:5], EMA, n=45)
```